# Spring Autowired vs Pass by Value

Tags: spring, autowired

When should I autowire a resource rather than pass it by value into the constructor and set it to be private.

For example,

```
@Autowired
private SystemLogger systemLogger
```

vs

```
public class derp {
 private SystemLogger systemLogger;   
 public derp(SystemLogger systemLogger){
        this.systemLogger = systemLogger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `SystemLogger` would seem to be an integral part of your class, I would pass it as a constructor argument. Personally, I think it makes it more obvious which collaborators your class needs to be properly initialised. It should also be final.

This also has the benefit of making your class easier to test using mocks. You could use mocks using `Autowired` on an attibute, but it would involve more effort (e.g. exposing a `setter` - which would be bad, or shoe-horning a mock into the `ApplicationContext`).

This may just come down to personal preference, but for what it's worth, the Spring Consultant  that led the Core Spring Training I attended recommended not using `Autowired` on class members.